# If url is a certain path then add parameter

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a script running where if there is a certain URL, then this will add a parameter. E.g. If this url subfolder has /de in, then add ?_sft_language=german. If /sp then add ?_sft_language=spanish. I have written the below code in JavaScript but it is running multiple times, but I only want it to run once.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(!window.location.href.match('_sft_language') && window.location.href.match('testsite.com/de/partner/')){var url = document.location.href+"?_sft_language=german";document.location = url;}   

    if(!window.location.href.match('_sft_language') && window.location.href.match('testsite.com/da/partner/')){var url = document.location.href+"?_sft_language=danish";document.location = url;}   
    if(!window.location.href.match('_sft_language') && window.location.href.match('testsite.com/nl/partner/')){var url = document.location.href+"?_sft_language=dutch";document.location = url;}    
    if(!window.location.href.match('_sft_language') && window.location.href.match('testsite.com/fr/partner/')){var url = document.location.href+"?_sft_language=french";document.location = url;}   
    if(!window.location.href.match('_sft_language') && window.location.href.match('testsite.com/it/partner/')){var url = document.location.href+"?_sft_language=italian";document.location = url;}  
    if(!window.location.href.match('_sft_language') && window.location.href.match('testsite.com/ja/partner/')){var url = document.location.href+"?_sft_language=japanese";document.location = url;} 
    if(!window.location.href.match('_sft_language') && window.location.href.match('testsite.com/ko/partner/')){var url = document.location.href+"?_sft_language=korean";document.location = url;}   
    if(!window.location.href.match('_sft_language') && window.location.href.match('testsite.com/no/partner/')){var url = document.location.href+"?_sft_language=norwegian";document.location = url;}    
    if(!window.location.href.match('_sft_language') && window.location.href.match('testsite.com/es/partner/')){var url = document.location.href+"?_sft_language=spanish";document.location = url;}  

    if(!window.location.href.match('_sft_language') && window.location.href.match('testsite.com/partner/')){var url = document.location.href+"?_sft_language=english";document.location = url;} 


});
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: This code will not execute multiple times unless you trigger the ready event manually. Normally the ready event is only executed after the DOM is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

you could check if you already added this parameter:

```
if(!window.location.href.match('_sft_language') && window.location.href.match('testingsite.com/de/partner')){
        var url = document.location.href+"?_sft_language=german";
        document.location = url;

}
```

Comment: Hi, so it would be something like this in my script:-

 if(!window.location.href.match('_sft_language') && window.location.href.match('testsite.com/de/partner')){var url = document.location.href+"?_sft_language=german";document.location = url;} 
 if(!window.location.href.match('_sft_language') && window.location.href.match('testsite.com/da/partner')){var url = document.location.href+"?_sft_language=danish";document.location = url;}

Comment: Hi @Malarres I have edited my answer to show what I am up to. But still not working as it needs to overwrite the previous parameter

Comment: if after your edit the code is still running multiple times i'm out of ideas :( Maybe is it related to other portion in the codebase?